# When using linux acl mkdir and mkdir -p do different things

Tags: linux, posix, acl, shell-builtin, mkdir

I have a directory `bar`:

```
# file: bar/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:little-jonny:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:little-jonny:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

If I create a directory inside bar with `mkdir baz`, I have for `baz`:

```
# file: baz/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:little-jonny:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:little-jonny:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

If I use `mkdir -p foo`, I have for `foo`:

```
# file: foo/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:little-jonny:rwx               #effective:r-x
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:little-jonny:rwx
default:group::r-x
default:mask::rwx
default:other::r-x
```

Why `mkdir -p` uses the default root rights when there is explicit rule that states `default:mask::rwx` if you are in `bar`?

How force `mkdir -p` to behave as `mkdir`? (Without always passing `-m775` when root and it should happen only when making directories in the `bar`)

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Are you sure that `foo` didn't already exist? What is your umask? What kernel version are you running, on what version of what distribution?

Comment: @Gilles It's a bug in coreutils http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=14371 :/ I'll most probably answer the question myself in a couple of hours. I haven't tested the latest version yet.